# Resolution of scanLRTS

Tags: r, spatstat

I want to increase the resolution of the output of `scanLRTS`. Changing the `dimyx` parameter only increases the dimensions of the output image, but not the pixel resolution of the output values. I have also unsuccessfully tried the `eps` and `xy` parameters.

```
plot(scanLRTS(shapley, 1, method="poisson"))
```

[image: base scanLRTS]

```
plot(scanLRTS(shapley, 1, dimyx = 200, method="poisson"))
```

[image: scanLRTS with changed dimyx parameter]

The only hack I found to increase the resolution is to change the global parameters via `spatstat.options(npixel=200)`

```
spatstat.options(npixel=200)
plot(scanLRTS(shapley, 1, method="poisson"))
reset.spatstat.options()
```

[image: scanLRTS with changed global parameter]

Is there another option how to achieve the same result without changing the global parameters of `spatstat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug.

It has been fixed in the development version of `spatstat.explore` (version `3.2-5.007` and later) available from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat.explore).